# How to Mixing files Of Cascade Classifiers OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv

i am using haar cascade for object detection and there are various multiple cascade is available so can I mix those code to make new cascade. 
below code shown that there are two cascade for face and eye detection so can i mix those code to make new cascade?

i haven't have tried because i am new in Python.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('sachin.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: What output would you like to achieve by mixing the cascade files? BTW short answer is NO you simply cannot concatenate two given haar cascade files in to a single file.

Comment: ohk thank you so much. actually i have to develop new cascade file for the my project so i think if it possible or not  and even i google it but does not show any match result for me.

Comment: OpenCV used nested cascade for eyes: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/facedetect.cpp#L237

Comment: is there any new way to develop  cascade for object detection?